# How to fetch the colour value or rgb value of an element in Firefox and Internet Explorer using Watir-webdriver?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

In test case automation I have to verify whether a button colour is changed to blue or not. I have used the below code for Chrome, Which is giving an RGB value of that button colour.

```
element = river.element(:xpath => "//button[text()='Today' and @class='selected_button']")
colorString = element.style("background")
```

or

```
colorString = element.style("background-color")  
putws colorString
```

output for the above code for chrome is:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(177, 219, 234) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

From the above output string I'm collecting RGB value and verifying it. This way is working fine for chrome,
but the same code is not working for Firefox or Internet Explorer. The same method I have used for chrome is returning "" (empty string) for Firefox and Internet Explorer. Is there any alternate way to fetch the colour value , or a way for colour verification?

Here I have attached DOM screenshot for 'Today' button:
[image]

I am adding another Element(Where I am facing issue) HTML/Style here for reference

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html style="overflow: hidden;" slick-uniqueid="1">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.selected {
 background-color: #FFFF99 !important;
 color: black !important;
}
.today {
 border: 1px solid #FFCC00 !important;
}
.datepicker .days .day {
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 4px;
 width: 28px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 17px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #E1E1E1;
 color: black;
}
.datepicker .days {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.datepicker .body {
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 5px;
 width: 230px;
 height: 178px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.datepicker {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 11px;
 min-width: 230px;
 height: 214px;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 line-height: normal;
 width: 100%;
}
#calendarWidget {
 height: 241px;
 min-width: 235px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: Arial !important;
}
#calendarDiv {
 padding-top: 4px;
}
.panel-leftpanel {
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 z-index: 1;
}
.splitter-panel-1 {
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1;
}
.splitter-root {
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}
.panel-main {
 background: #efefef;
}
.panel-window {
 background: #ddd;
}
.fake_main_window_margin {
 border-style: solid;
 border-left-width: 0px;
 border-right-width: 0px;
 border-top-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
#cs_panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 130px;
 left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: #C8C8C8;
}
body {
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div class="fake_main_window_margin link_style" id="cs_panel" style="width: 

1280px; height: 293px;"><div class="panel-window" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 

width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div class="panel-main" 

style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div 

class="splitter-root" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; 

position: absolute;"><div class="splitter-panel-1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 

width: 252px; height: 100%; overflow: auto; position: absolute;"><div 

class="panel-leftpanel" id="filter-left-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 

100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; position: absolute;"><div id="leftPane"><div 

id="calendarDiv"><div class=" " id="calendarWidget"><div class="datepicker" 

id="datepicker" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; visibility: visible; 

-ms-zoom: 1; opacity: 1;"><div class="body"><div class="slider" style="left: 0px; 

top: 13px; width: 460px; height: 178px; position: absolute;"><div style="left: 

0px; top: 0px; width: 230px; height: 178px; visibility: visible; position: 

absolute; opacity: 1;"><div class="days"><div class="week week4"><div class="day 

day3 today selected 2015-05-27 

">27</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

</div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: `style("background-color")` is working for me in Firefox - ie I get an rgba. Can you create an minimal working HTML page that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `style("background-color)` is also working for Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I just tried IE and it also returns a result.

Comment: When I have tried in my application I get different output for different browsers. For IE the same method output was "transparent". and In chrome it was "rgb(177, 219, 234)". And in the UI element color was yellow at the time of execution

Comment: Can you please share the HTML/CSS that reproduces the problem? Though I would not be surprised if different browsers formatted the returned value differently.

Comment: @Justin Ko - are you able to check with the above snippet?

Comment: What should I be checking in the snippet (ie Watir code)? It seems to be different than the one your originally posted.

Comment: I have been facing the above issue in both the situations. So I could collect source for second one.. And the results are as I mentioned in the above comment for both browsers IE and Chrome